# code coloring like google developers website

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, phpstorm

I wonder if any of you guys know that what code color scheme google is using on the google developers website (in code view section). I want same syntax highlighting, code coloring and font. Is there any theme available containing all these colors and font? I'm using phpstorm. I'm a front end dev and I need it for html5, css3 and Javascirpt. Maybe the image can explain more than that I've to say.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: those color schemes are obsolete now

Comment: You can customize it.